# How to create global functions in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm developing an iphone app and I need to have some functions to use globally in my classes.

But how can I do this?

I just tried to create `functions.h` likes this

```
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>

- (void)printTest;
```

and in the `functions.m`

```
#import "functions.h"

- (void)prinTest {
    NSLog(@"test");
}
```

but it doesn't work. Says me: "Method definition not in a @implementation context".

Answer (score 64, accepted):

First note that Objective-C language is a superset of C language (meaning there is absolutely nothing wrong with mixing them).

There are two approaches.

### #1 Real global function:

Declare a global C-style function, which can have ObjC logic (in definetion instead of just C-style logic).

Header:

```
void GSPrintTest();
```

Implementation:

```
#import "functions.h"

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

void GSPrintTest() {
  NSLog(@"test");
}
```

Call using:

```
#import "functions.h"
...
GSPrintTest();
```

A third (bad, but possible) option would be adding a category to NSObject for your methods:

Header:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSObject(GlobalStuff)
- (void) printTest;
@end
```

Implementation:

```
#import "functions.h"

@implementation NSObject(GlobalStuff)
- (void) printTest {
  NSLog(@"test");
}
@end
```

Call using:

```
#import "functions.h"
...
[self printTest];
```

### #2 class method:

Create a class method with `+` sign, in helper class (instead of instance method with `-` sign).

Header:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface GlobalStuff : NSObject {}

+ (void)printTest;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
#import "functions.h"

@implementation GlobalStuff

+ (void) printTest {
  NSLog(@"test");
}

@end
```

Call using:

```
#import "functions.h"

...
[GlobalStuff printTest];
```

Comment: The first two ways works well. Except the second one that returns a warning: `No previous prototype for GSPrintTest()`. Is it normal? Anyway the first method it's very good. Only a question: Why don't I need to create an instance of that class for use it?

Comment: As for the second problem, it looks now like I have GKPrintTest instead of GSPrintTest, but that's probably not your problem.  Did you remember to include functions.h in the file where you call it as well as the file containing the implementation of GSPrintTest?

Comment: And to answer the first question, you don't need an instance because it is a static method, declared to be a member of the class itself rather than of instances of the class.  So you're calling a method on an object just like normal, except the object is a class instead of an instance.

Answer (score 16):

When you want a *global function*, just write a regular C function. The Objective-C syntax is meant to be used solely in the context of *object methods*.

```
void printTest() {
    NSLog(@"This is a test");
}
```

You also have to add the declaration in the `functions.h` header:

```
void printTest();
```

Comment: My function it's an Obj-C function that accepts arguments as normally. In your way the warning is: "No previous prototypefor 'printTest'".

Comment: @Fred Collins - There is no such thing as an Obj-C function. Objective-C implements only Objective-C methods and C functions.

Comment: And how would pass the parameters to this function?

Comment: @Resty simply write the arguments using the C-style, e.g: `BOOL isEvenNumber(NSNumber * number);` or `NSData * readFileAtPath(NSURL * path);`

Comment: Bounty sent to @Eelke for a very informative old answer!

Answer (score 4):

Simple. Your setup is almost perfect.

Just `#include` your `Functions.h` in all classes that need it, and you should be all set. I do it all the time.

You will have to use some kind of object, but you can make it "feel" just like a global objective-c function by using a **category** of `NSObject`:

- Create a new file and choose *Objective C Category*.
- Make it a category of `NSObject`.
- Use the templates provided to define and implement your methods.

Now you can use them simply by invoking

```
[self myCategoryMethod:optionalParameter];
```

Comment: As already said, it returns me `Method definition not in a @implementation context`. Can you show me how you use it all the time?

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename `functions.m` into `functions.c`.

Or add this methods into some class `SharedClass` and decline them as static : `+ (void)prinTest`. Then you can access them using this code

```
[SharedClass printTest];
```

Comment: Yep I know I can use singleton classes but probably, only for some methods, it's useless. Don't think so?

Comment: I think, it is ok. Why do you see any problems?

Answer (score 0):

What your error is referring to is you need to have that method in an interface.

```
@interface SomeClass
- (void)printTest;
@end
```

To use a static void throughout your app *(where you have included your Functions.h)*, try the following:

```
void printTest ()
{
    /* do your print stuff */
}
```

Comment: I don't want any class. I would only simple function.