# Creating "Global Methods"

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create global functions in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294176/how-to-create-global-functions-in-objective-c)

I am curious how it is commonly done to create global utility methods in Objective C that any Class can use.

The simple and only solution I can think of is to simply create a class, i.e. call it GlobalMethods, and just create a bunch of class methods so that they can be used without this class ever getting instantiated.

Is this a wise and valid approach? Regarding the type of methods, they might be anything, for example custom math formulas I use, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few common ways to make some code usable globally.  Here are some, with examples from Apple's public APIs:

- Create class methods on a new class.  This is what you suggested.  Examples: `NSPropertyListSerialization`, `NSJSONSerialization`.
- Create class methods on some appropriate existing class.  Example: UIKit uses a category to add class methods to `NSValue`, such as `valueWithCGRect:` and `valueWithCGPoint:`.
- Create a singleton that understands some group of related messages.  Examples: `[UIApplication sharedApplication]`, `[NSFileManager defaultManager]`.
- Create plain old C functions.  Examples: `UIImagePNGRepresentation`, `UIRectFill`, `NSLog`, `NSStringFromCGPoint`, and a pantload more.
- If the code operates on some object in particular, add a method the the object's class using a category.  Example: `UIKit` adds `sizeWithFont:`, `drawAtPoint:withFont:`, and related methods to `NSString` using a category.

Answer (score 1):

I use that exact approach to provide my global `CocoaUtil` class that provides various application services.

However you can simply define global C functions that do Objective-C things; for example:

Util.h:

```
extern NSString *helloWorld(int i);
```

Util.m:

```
NSString *helloWorld(int i)
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello World %d", i];
}
```

However, I use the Objective-C class approach as it provides better "namespace" support, ala C++.