# Global Functions Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am trying to write a global function however keep getting the error "No visible interface...." when i try and call it.

Popover.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Popover : NSObject{}

- (void)PopoverPlay;

@end
```

Popover.m

```
#import "Popover.h"

@implementation Popover

- (void)PopoverPlay{
     NSLog(@"I Work");
}

@end
```

In View.m i am adding the import "Popover.h" but i cant get rid of the error message when i try and run.

```
#import "View.h" 
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "Popover.h"

@interface View ()
{
}
@end

@implementation View

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    // Custom initialization

    }
    return self;
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (IBAction)ButtonPress {
    [self PopoverPlay];
}
```

Any ideas
Thanks

Comment: Please provide code for view.m

Comment: Check this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294176/how-to-create-global-functions-in-objective-c

Comment: PupilView is not a subclass of Popover, hence the method `PopoverPlay` is not defined as a method of View.  When you use `self` in View `self` is pointing to the current instance of View.

Comment: Methods should always start with lowercase letters.

Answer (score 3):

The code you've shown is the declaration and definition of a class that contains a single instance method. To use it, you'll need to allocate an instance of `Popover` with code that looks something like:

```
#import "Popover.h"

//...
Popover *pop = [[Popover alloc] init];
[pop PopoverPlay];
//...
```

When people talk about "global functions" they don't usually mean instance methods (or even class methods), so I doubt this is quite what you're after. Perhaps you mean an actual function that you can call from other parts of your code? You'd do that the same way you do in C:

```
void foo(void);

void foo(void)
{
    NSLog(@"This works");
}
```

If you add the prototype (first line) to a header file, you can use the function anywhere in any file that includes that header.

**Update:**

```
- (IBAction)ButtonPress {
    [self PopoverPlay];
}
```

The problem here is that you're sending `-PopoverPlay` to `self`, but `self` in this case represents an instance of `View`. You need to send `-PopoverPlay` to an instance of the class that implements it, which is `Popover`. See my example above. (BTW, your interface and implementation don't match: one is `PupilView` and the other is `View`.)

Comment: hi there, the pupilview/view issue was me simplifying but i missed a pupilview when changing it

Answer (score 0):

To call the method you wrote, you need to do something like:

```
Popover *myPopover = [[Popover alloc] init];
[myPopover PopoverPlay];
```

What you have is an *instance* method.  Because your method doesn't rely on any instance variables, you could make it a *class* method by changing the `-` to `+`:

```
+ (void)PopoverPlay;
```

and

```
+ (void)PopoverPlay{
```

Then you don't need to initialize a new `Popover`; you can just call:

```
[Popover PopoverPlay];
```