# Call global function on button click in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a common file for functions using the following link as a guide. The only difference is instead of importing the common file in each file i wish to use it, i globally import it in the %ProjectName%-Prefix.pch file.

[How to create global functions in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294176/how-to-create-global-functions-in-objective-c)

In my file where i want to use the function all i have is the following and it works. It calls the test function, which simply prints test to the console.

`[Common test];`

Now i want to add the function to a button with the following:

```
UIBarButtonItem *btnBack= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Arrows-Back.png"]
                                                           style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                          target:self
                                                          action:@selector([Common test])];
```

It says "Expected identifier", and doesnt compile.

Ive tried several variations like

- setting the target to "Common" (the name for my interface)
- removing the "@selector" from the action
- creating an instance of common ex `Common c = [[Common alloc] init]` and then using `[c test]`

Cant seem to figure out how to call this global function from a button action.

Thanks,

Comment: I think you should change the target from `self` to your common object.

Comment: Try setting 'c' as target.

Comment: @ipinak when i set target to Common, it says unexpected interface name 'Common'; expected expression

Comment: @Arcanfel when i declare ```Common c = [[Common alloc] init];``` it says "Interface type cannot be statically allocated". So i dont even get that chance to put that as the target.

Comment: What you've described is a class method, not a global function.

Comment: @jlehr I dont really know the difference. Im still learning.

Comment: @ToddHorst sorry, rephrase: set it your instance of common object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the target to `[Common class]` and action to `@selector(test)`

Answer (score 1):

You could write a method in your current class:

```
-(void) test {
    [Common test];
}
```

And then set the target to `self` and the action to `@selector(test)`

Comment: that would work, but i dont want to create a pointer to the function each time i want to do this. That almost defeat the purpose as the test function will only be a line or two, when its complete

Comment: There are organizational advantages to having all of your button actions, etc. go through the view controller that the parent view is associated with.  In any case, I've posted another answer that should be more to your liking.

Comment: Close @stackunderflow — you want `@selector(test)` for the action.