# Globally declaring a function pointer in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, function-pointers

I want to globally declare a function pointer in Objective C. I want to do this because I'm fetching updates for a notification asynchronously, and I'd like the completion handler to be used once all the updates have been received.

The header is declared as follows:

```
@interface GetStatusUpdate : NSObject 
{
    void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult) completionHandler;    
}

-(void)getStatusUpdate:(NSDictionary*)details completionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandle;

@end
```

I'm happy (I think) that I'm passing the completion handler correctly in getStatusUpdate, but the declaration "void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult) completionHandler" doesn't compile.

In the interests of completeness, I was going to:

```
-(void)getStatusUpdate:(NSDictionary*)journeyDetails
     completionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandle {

    completionHandler = completionHandle;
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?  Any suggestions how I might use completion handler 'better' after an asynchronous fetch?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294176/how-to-create-global-functions-in-objective-c

Comment: The proper title for this question would be "How to declare an instance variable of block type?" It's neither "global", nor function pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name is in the wrong place:

```
@interface GetStatusUpdate : NSObject 
{ 
    void (^completionHandler)(UIBackgroundFetchResult);    
}
```

Then, some where, you have to define the block:

```
completionHandler = ^(UIBackgroundFetchResult result) {
    // do your work
};
```

or assign it as you did.

I find this helpful when I have to work with blocks: http://fuckingblocksyntax.com/

As an aside, your block is being stored as an instance variable, **not** a global variable.

Answer (score 2):

Block are sometimes called anonymous functions. Why? because they do not have a distinct uniquely defined name (they are anonymous) and really distinguish themselves only by their signature (input parameters and their output).

So in your case, it is not really necessary to have your block defined globaly.
Because when you will call the `-(void)getStatusUpdate:completionHandler:`
in some other class, you will simply construct a block that will have the same signature, together with block's implementation and pass it as a parameter.

It would look like this (notice the block instance variable gone):

```
@interface GetStatusUpdate : NSObject

-(void)getStatusUpdate:(NSDictionary*)details 
     completionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult *result))paramCompletionHandlerBlock;

@end
```

and calling the method in some other class (where statusUpdateInstance is an instance of GetStatusUpdate class) like this:

```
 [statusUpdateInstance getStatusUpdate:detailsDictionaryInstance 
                     completionHandler:^(UIBackgroundFetchResult *result)
                                       {
                                          //code that processes "result"...
                                       }];
```

Btw. I fixed the blocks signature, the input parameter must be named.

---

**For the discussion about the blocks scope (have it more global as you say) to make any sense**, you need to **typedef** the block. It will not be that "anonymous" anymore, as it will be know as a distinct type.
Where is the right place to typedef the block? Well, any class that wants to call  `-(void)getStatusUpdate:completionHandler:` method, needs to import the `GetStatusUpdate` class. Only classes that call that method really need to know the block, no other ones.

So it only makes sense to declare and typedef that block in the public interface of the `GetStatusUpdate` class. 
We will give the block the `FetchResultsCompletionBlock` name because this is what the block really does and it will look like this>

```
typedef void(^FetchResultsCompletionBlock)(UIBackgroundFetchResult *result);

@interface GetStatusUpdate : NSObject

-(void)getStatusUpdate:(NSDictionary*)details completionHandler:(FetchResultsCompletionBlock)completionHandle;

@end
```

Notice that once this block is typedef-ed i.e. represents a distinct known type,
thi signature of `-(void)getStatusUpdate:completionHandler:` method is dramatically simplified.