# Method Not Found in ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to create a global function or method in objectiveC. This is so that I can call it from any of my view controllers.

I already checked out this post: [How to create global functions in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294176/how-to-create-global-functions-in-objective-c)

So what I did was in Xcode 6 I created new file and choose a category drop down. that created these two *.h & *.m files for me. I added my method called SaveWeatherDataNow in it

```
//NSObject+SaveWeatherData.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSObject (SaveWeatherData)

+(void)SaveWeatherDataNow:(NSString *)XML;

@end

//NSObject+SaveWeatherData.m
#import "NSObject+SaveWeatherData.h"

@implementation NSObject (SaveWeatherData)

+(void)SaveWeatherDataNow:(NSString *)XML
{

    NSLog(@"SaveWeatherDataNow XML lenght: %ld", [XML length]);
}

@end
```

Now in my another view controller if I call this method then complier doesn't find it at all. What did I miss?

```
//  v1CitiesAdd.m
#import "NSObject+SaveWeatherData.h"

@implementation v1CitiesAdd
...
...
-(IBAction) doneAction
{

...
[SaveWeatherData SaveWeatherDataNow:XML]; // Complier Error: Use of undeclared identifier SaveWeatherData
```

Comment: `[NSObject SaveWeatherDataNow:XML];` should work.

Comment: That did it. I feel so dumb. Can you also tell me what's the difference between +(void) and -(void) ... some tutorials have + others have - in front of the methods.

Comment: If you have only one object, that will be fine.  If you have different objects, you'll need to switch it to the -(void) so it would use the internal class's data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `+` to a `-` (in front of `(void)`):

```
-(void)SaveWeatherDataNow:(NSString *)XML;
```

That way, you can refer to the method within your SaveWeatherData object.

Don't forget to change it in both the header (.h) file as well as the class (.m) file.

You could also call

[NSObject SaveWeatherDataNow:XML];

by leaving the +.

===

When you use a +, it's a class method.  It works globally, and doesn't know or care about individual objects.

When you use a -, it's an object method.  It works within a specific object.

So, if there is a Brick class,

+(void) smash;

would change/update every brick to be smashed.

-(void) shatter;

would shatter a specific brick you send that message to.

[myBrick1 shatter]; would only shatter the one brick.

[Brick smash]; would change something globally for all bricks.

Comment: + is for static functions (that belong to a class), - is for functions that belong to the instances

Comment: Thanks Jeff, please add brigad's answer and I will mark yours

Answer (score 2):

I am writing a different answer, because I think the best answer to this question would be **Don't do it!**.

To create a category for `NSObject` to save data is a very ugly thing to do.

**WHY**

It would mean that when you import it to a class EVERY class that inherits from NSObject (almost all of them) would suddenly have that extra method.

For example, code like this would work:

```
NSNumber *myInt = @(3)
NSString *myXmlAsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<rating>%@</rating>",myInt.integerValue];
```

If you keep using the static method (with +) you could do:

```
[NSObject SaveWeatherDataNow:myXmlAsString];
```

or

```
[NSNumber SaveWeatherDataNow:myXmlAsString];
```

or even

```
[UIImage SaveWeatherDataNow:myXmlAsString];
```

If you change it to an instance method (with -), you could do:

```
[myXmlAsString SaveWeatherDataNow:myXmlAsString];
```

or

```
[myInt SaveWeatherDataNow:myXmlAsString];
```

or use most of the existing variables in that scope, which would seem very strange to say the least.

**WHAT YOU SHOUD DO INSTEAD**

I would use one of following 2 options:

1. Create a class that manages data saving/loading for you. The usage should then look like this:

   `[DataManager saveWeatherDataNow:myXmlAsString];`
2. If you don't need that much, only that function, you could create a Utility class and add that static method (in case you do not have one already).

   `[Utility saveWeatherDataNow:myXmlAsString];`

PS: by convention, you usually start method names with lowercase.

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate a little as to why one should use a class Vs category. I mean if I create a global method, they both will do the same thing. Is it that one is more efficient at run time than the other? Is there better performance with one than the other or its just a good convention to always use class instead of category? Sorry, I am just trying to understand.

Comment: It is not always besser to use class over category, it depends on what you are doing. Classes and methods represent an idea. A class is a type of object (like a car) and a method is something that object can do (like open doors). What you are saying is that every object can save weather data (a car or a banana saving weather data??). From the idea point of view it just makes no sense. You should try to have an architecture that makes sense, so it can be maintained. If you were to add all functions to a category of NSObject, you will end up with all Objects having millions of functions.

Comment: Thus, you will never be able to find the ones that really belong to the object, and you will be completely lost in your own code.

Answer (score 0):

> `[SaveWeatherData SaveWeatherDataNow:XML]; // Complier Error: Use of undeclared identifier SaveWeatherData`

The root of the problem here is that you haven't defined a class named `SaveWeatherData`. Instead, you've created a category on `NSObject`, so that you can call `+SaveWeatherDataNow:` on any class that's derived from `NSObject`. The straightforward solution is to create a class instead of a category. Change these lines:

```
@interface NSObject (SaveWeatherData)
@implementation NSObject (SaveWeatherData)
```

to these:

```
@interface SaveWeatherData
@implementation SaveWeatherData
```

and that should allow a call like this:

```
[SaveWeatherData SaveWeatherDataNow:XML];
```

to work correctly.

Comment: Hey Caleb, is there a typo in your answer? If I specify my class as @interface SaveWeatherData I get a build warning that Class SaveWeatherData is defined without specifying a base class.