# Undefined symbols for architecture in Xcode / Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I wanted to refactor my iOS app written in Objective-C. I created a new class Utility (files Utility.h and Utility.m).

This is my header Utility.h (Type: Default C Header)

```
//  Utility.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h> 
NSAttributedString *attributedTitle(NSString *title);
```

This is my implementation file Utility.m (Type: Default - Objective-C Source)

```
 // Utility.m
 #import "Utility.h"
 NSAttributedString *attributedTitle(NSString *title) {
    NSAttributedString *attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title];
    return attributedTitle;
}
```

This file is a member of my target and is added in the "Build Phases -> Compile Source" (first file in fact). Foundation and UIKit are also linked.

I'm using this method in a different Objective-C file:

```
// OtherClass.m
#import "OtherClass.h"
#import "Utility.h"
@implementation OtherClass
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
         NSAttributedString *string = attributedTitle(@"hello");
         NSLog(@"%@", string);
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

This .m file is also a member of my target. The error I'm receiving is

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 "_attributedTitle", referenced from:
          -[OtherClass.m init] in OtherClass.o
```

Comment: @jtbandes added full example

Comment: @matt I do have the .m part of the target :(

Comment: @matt sorry I think that's the issue then. The attributedTitle method was a static method in my class and I wanted to take it somewhere else to use it in other classes as well.

Comment: @matt I'm actually unsure now what to do with that static method. I'd like to use it in other classes as well

Comment: I'm confused by this discussion. It looks like OP is trying to use a function, not a method, and there's nothing wrong with that. There is no "Utility class".

Comment: @matt I'm still thinking about this and I'm actually unsure why I can't do such a thing? Thanks by the way and if you type the error in an answer I'll accept it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @matt so if you have a static method that does some formatting stuff and you want to use it in multiple classes, what is a reasonable way to do so? just add it to a header (full implementation) because that works.

Comment: @ jtbandes yeah I'm unsure. thanks.

Comment: @matt sorry there is no swift. it was a static method in the same class "OtherClass" declared at the very top. I'd like to move this function out of this class to use it in other classes.

Comment: #Otherclass.m
static NSAttributedString *attributedTitle(NSString *title) {
}
implementation OtherClass 
....
end

Comment: @matt it was defined in OtherClass.m like the above. I just took it out to Utility. I think have some fundamentals wrong. I need to do more readings. Sorry

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294176/how-to-create-global-functions-in-objective-c

Comment: Also is this your real code? You can't say `[NSAttributedString initWithString...`; you are missing an `alloc`. So I would expect that not even to compile.

Comment: @matt sorry again. I corrected my example. I was reading the link and I thought I was doing option 2 by declaring a function in Utility.h and implementing it in Utility.m. I'm re-reading now. Thanks again for the help and the link

Answer (score 0):

I feel very certain, despite your claims to the contrary, that what I said in my first comment is right: *Utility.m* is not part of the app target.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of the Utility class looks like C, but it is not correct. Did you compile it?

I suggest you override Utility and change the method to a class method. like this

```
// Utility.h
+ (NSAttributedString *)attributedTitle:(NSString *title);
```

```
// Utility.m

+ (NSAttributedString *)attributedTitle:(NSString *title) {
    NSAttributedString *attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title];
    return attributedTitle;
}
```

When you use it, you can use it like this

```
NSAttributedString *string = [Utility attributedTitle:@"hello"];
```